# how to find the file containing error?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, angular-material2, typescript2.0

hy.  I have just updated my app to angular 4.4.3 and the latest angular material. After tons of errors now I get only one, but it looks like little confusing because it is hard to understand what is the name of file error is in.
I got error:

```
(SystemJS) Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]
    Error: Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]
        at invalidProviderError (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1317:12)
        at eval (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2118:19)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at _normalizeProviders (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2107:15)
        at eval (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2115:13)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at _normalizeProviders (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2107:15)
        at resolveReflectiveProviders (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2058:39)
        at Function.ReflectiveInjector.resolve (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2287:16)
        at Function.ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2319:79)
    Evaluating http://localhost:8080/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/main.js
        at invalidProviderError (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1317:12)
        at eval (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2118:19)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at _normalizeProviders (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2107:15)
        at eval (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2115:13)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at _normalizeProviders (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2107:15)
        at resolveReflectiveProviders (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2058:39)
        at Function.ReflectiveInjector.resolve (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2287:16)
        at Function.ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2319:79)
    Evaluating http://localhost:8080/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/main.js
```

Can you help me? What is the file the error is in?
I thought that error is in file main.ts, but there is only just a few lines:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

There is only one place in `AppModule` may be related with `providers` :

```
//changes languages that are set locally
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';


@NgModule({
    imports: [...,

 TranslateModule.forRoot({

            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [Http]
            }

        })
```

Also, there is other place in other component file which is routed:

```
//used for listing json as treeview
import {
   TreeviewI18n,
    TreeviewItem, TreeviewConfig,
    TreeviewHelper,
    TreeviewComponent,
    TreeviewEventParser, OrderDownlineTreeviewEventParser,
    DownlineTreeviewItem
} from 'ngx-treeview';


@Component({

    selector: '...',

   templateUrl: '...',

    providers: [HttpService, 
        { provide: TreeviewEventParser, useClass: OrderDownlineTreeviewEventParser }
    ]


})
```

Comment: you got a problem with the Invalid provider  and the object of this need to be [object Object]. But add your code because isn't a answer, it's just what the debug error said.

Comment: The problem is inside your `AppModule`, you are adding a wrong 'thing' into your AppModules `providers` array. Post the code of your `AppModule`

Comment: @PierreDuc could you please see my updated post?

Comment: @AmoT Post your **full** `AppModule` please.

Answer (score 1):

Check providers in your module - you probably pass object instead of provider class.